# chrome site paswords are lost when I switch between Gnome and Kde

Tags: gnome, kubuntu, google-chrome, kde

I installed ubuntu 20.04.
I also installed the KDE desktop
I login via gnome, start google chrome and save the login credentials of a site.
When I login again via kde, start google chrome the credentials of the above site are lost.
How can this be fixed?
Regards,
vhelmont

EDIT: With both window managers Chrome shows the correct profile directory, `/home/vhelmont/.config/google-chrome/Default`

Comment: In a terminal please try entering `echo $CHROME_CONFIG_HOME`. Do that both from KDE and Gnome and let us know the output.

Comment: Both gnome and kde return an empty string

Comment: Hmm, ok, how about if you navigate to `chrome://version` and check the profile directory that way. (https://www.howtogeek.com/255653/how-to-find-your-chrome-profile-folder-on-windows-mac-and-linux/). If they don't match that is definitely the issue.

Comment: They both are: Profile Path /home/vhelmont/.config/google-chrome/Default

Comment: So we eliminated that. I've submitted an edit to include that in the question.